# Android: How to replace the fragment page by fragment activity

Tags: android

I'm using a navigation drawer in project. the drawer items calls(redirect) to a fragment page. i need to call a fragmentActivity page. 
can anyone give some suggestion for this

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with:

```
getActivity().startActivity(intent)
```